# Can I reuse variable that has been written to set?

Tags: c++

Function code:

```
std::set<OutputData> results;
OutputData od;
    for (unsigned int qt = 0; qt < sizeof(allResultTypes); qt++)
    {
            //for each ResultType loop through all dates (Labels property)
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(allDates[i]); i++)
            {

                //write date to the ExposureData object
                od.date = JsonParser::allLabels[i];

                if (allResultTypes[qt] == "type_A")
                {
                    od.type_A = allData[i];
                }

                if (allResultTypes[qt] == "type_B")
                {
                    od.type_B = allData[i];
                }

                results.insert(od);
            }       
    }
```

Output data class;

```
struct OutputData
{
    int32_t date;
    double type_A;
    double type_B;
};
```

Question:

1) Once od is inserted to the results set can I wipe content of od variable? I would like to reuse od object that way;

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(allDates[i]); i++)
            {
                if (od != nullptr) 
                {
                    od.date = nullptr;
                    od.type_A = nullptr;
                    od.type_B = nullptr;
                }
                //write date to the ExposureData object
                od.date = JsonParser::allLabels[i];

                if (allResultTypes[qt] == "type_A")
                {
                    od.type_A = allData[i];
                }
                if (allResultTypes[qt] == "type_B")
                {
                    od.type_B = allData[i];
                }
                results.insert(od);
            }
```

Is that correct or I am nullifing the content of set that has been added by preceding loop iteration?

Comment: `sizeof` is probably not what you want. if you use container, you probably want `.size()`.

Comment: When you insert an object into any container it is *copied*. The container will contain a copy of the object, at the time of insertion. What you then do with the original object will not reflect on the copy.

Comment: `od = nullptr;` has no sense. but yes you can reuse `od` once inserted in `set`, as `set` does a copy.

Comment: @Jarod42 you mean that just overwritting od with a new values would be enough; actually I should say there od.date = nullptr;od.type_A=nullptr and od.type_B nullptr;

Comment: Thanks @Some programmer dude, you answered my question as it seems